# Non-linear integro-differential equation with infinite domain of integration

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerics, nonlinear, integral-equations

$$I(t)=\frac{dy(t)}{dt}+\int_{-\infty}^t dt'\left[\sin\left(\frac{y(t)-y(t')}{2}\right)f(t-t')-\sin\left(\frac{y(t)+y(t')}{2}\right)g(t-t')\right]$$
with $y(t\leq 0)=0$ and $I(t)=I_0\Theta(t)$ with $\Theta(t)$ being the Heaviside step function. $f$ and $g$ are known, well-behaved functions, which we can take as $f(\tau)=g(\tau)=\frac{\tau}{(1+\tau^2)^2}$.

I am currently solving it self-consistently in Matlab starting with a guess for $y(t)$, and using the derivative term to do a finite difference update of $y(t)$. That is,
$$y_{new}(t+\Delta t)=\Delta t\left(I(t)-\int_{-\infty}^t dt'\left[\sin\left(\frac{y_{old}(t)-y_{old}(t')}{2}\right)f(t-t')-\sin\left(\frac{y_{old}(t)+y_{old}(t')}{2}\right)g(t-t')\right]\right)$$ I was wondering if there is possibly a neater way to solve this on Mathematica.

Comment: Questions should usually contain code. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integro-differential equation also can be solved using the Delay Differential Equation feature of `NDSolve`.  This involves discretizing the integral, for instance by

```
tmax = 50;
fi = FunctionInterpolation[t^2/(1 + t^2)/2, {t, 0, tmax}, MaxRecursion -> 10];
```

where `t^2/(1 + t^2)/2` is the integral of `f`, determined in my earlier answer. The resulting `InterpolationFunction` contains values of the integral (`84` in total) at

```
cs = Flatten@fi["Coordinates"]
(* {0., 0.000529258, 0.00211033, ... 41.6667, 45.8333, 50.} *)
```

with the values themselves,

```
fi["ValuesOnGrid"]
(* {0., 0.000529258, 0.00211033. ... 0.499712, 0.499762, 0.4998} *)
```

from which weights can be computed,

```
ws = -MovingAverage[Subtract @@@ Partition[Join[{%[[1]]}, %, {%[[-1]]}], 2, 1], 2]
(* {0.000264629, 0.00105517, 0.00209703, ... 0.0000586998, 0.0000439571, 0.0000189916} *)
```

Not surprisingly, `Total@ws` equals `0.4998` to high accuracy.  There are, of course, several ways to discretize the integral, but this one is straightforward and efficient.  Applying this discretization to the differential equation given near the beginning of my earlier answer then yields after a small amount of algebra,

```
eq = D[y[t], t] == i0 + 2 Cos[y[t]/2] 
    Sum[ws[[i]] Sin[y[t - cs[[i]]]/2], {i, Length[cs]}];
```

Solving `eq` with `i0 = 1` then yields the same result obtain in my earlier answer in a few seconds, rather than the `4480` seconds needed previously.  In fact, the ten solutions for `i0 = Range[.1, 1., .1]` can be obtained in `19` seconds.

```
Do[i0 = j/10; 
  eq = D[y[t], t] == i0 + 2 Cos[y[t]/2] 
    Sum[ws[[i]] Sin[y[t - cs[[i]]]/2], {i, Length[cs]}];
  s[j] = NDSolveValue[{eq, y[t /; t <= 0] == 0}, y[t], {t, 0, tmax}], {j, 10}]

Plot[Evaluate@Array[s, 10], {t, 0, tmax}, ImageSize -> Large, 
  AxesLabel -> {t, y}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Placed[Range[.1, 1., .1], {.1, .6}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The integro-differential equation can be solved with only a modest amount of code, as follows:  First note that the integrand can be simplified because, as stated in the question, `f[r] == g[r]`.

```
int = (Sin[(y[t] - y[tp])/2] - Sin[(y[t] + y[tp])/2]) f[t - tp];
Simplify[int]
(* -2 Cos[y[t]/2] f[t - tp] Sin[y[tp]/2] *)
```

and `-2 Cos[y[t]/2]` can be moved from within the integral.  Additionally, because `y[tp]` vanishes for `tp <= 0`, the lower bound on the integral can be increased from `-Infinity` to `0`.  Consequently, the integro-differential equation reduces to

```
D[y[t], t] == i0 + 2 Cos[y[t]/2] 
  NIntegrate[Sin[y[tp]/2] (t - tp)/(1 + (t - tp)^2)^2, {tp, 0, t}]
```

Unfortunately, `NDSolve` is unable to handle such equations.  It turns out, though, that the equation can be solved iteratively.  For instance, with `i0 = 1`,

```
Clear[s, h];
n = 14; tmax = 50; i0 = 1;
s[0] = FunctionInterpolation[i0 t, {t, 0, tmax}];
Do[
  h[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Sin[s[i - 1][tp]/2] 
    (t - tp)/(1 + (t - tp)^2)^2, {tp, 0, t}]; 
  s[i] = NDSolveValue[{D[y[t], t] == i0 + 2 Cos[y[t]/2] h[t], y[0] == 0}, 
    y, {t, 0, tmax}], {i, 1, n}];
Plot[Evaluate@Array[s[#][t] &, n + 1, 0], {t, 0, tmax}, ImageSize -> Large, 
  AxesLabel -> {t, y}, LabelStyle -> {15, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

Successive iterations lead to progressively lower curves, with good convergence obtained with ten iterations.  Values at `t = tmax` illustrate the convergence.

```
Array[s[#][tmax] &, n + 1, 0]
(* 50., 48.5208, 47.4234, 45.481, 43.3451, 42.2148, 41.175, 39.5509, 
   37.8209, 36.9781, 36.6383, 36.4922, 36.4351, 36.4158, 36.41} *)
```

The computation takes about an hour.

**Addendum: Asymptotically constant solutions.**

Suppose that `y[t]` is approximately constant for large `t`.  Then, `Sin[y[t]/2]` can be removed from within the integral, leaving

```
Integrate[(t - tp)/(1 + (t - tp)^2)^2, {tp, 0, t}, Assumptions -> t > 0]
{* t^2/(2 + 2 t^2) *}
```

which reduces to `1/2` for large `t`, and the integro-differential equation collapses to `i0 == -Sin[y/2]/2`.  Hence, asymptotically flat solutions exist if and only if `-1/2 < i0 < 1/2`, and the asymptotic values should be, for `i0 = {1/10, 2/10, 3/10, 4/10, 5/10}`,

```
N@Table[Min@SolveValues[{Sin[x]/2 == -j, Pi < x < 2 Pi}, x], {j, 1/10, 5/10, 1/10}]
(* {3.34295, 3.55311, 3.78509, 4.06889, 4.71239} *)
```

The earlier code block gives corresponding converged solutions at `tmax = 50` of

```
(* {3.34306, 3.55333, 3.78547, 4.06955, 4.61028} *)
```

Evidently, the `i0 = 1/2` solution is not yet in the asymptotic regime at `tmax = 50`.  Corresponding converged solutions are

[image]

Comment: @eveningsilverfox You may find my recently added small `i0` solutions of interest.